# object object in php from ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

In my php I'm getting

```
string(15) "[object Object]"
```

I'm posting from ajax an array consisting of:

```
ctx.imageData.push({name : file.name, value : this.result});
```

this.result is a base64 encoded image, taken from a js file reader.

How can I get the contents of object object in php?

Comment: simply `var_dump` it and see what it contains

Comment: @Laimoncijus — It contains string(15) "[object Object]"

Comment: "I'm posting from ajax" — How? You need to show enough code for people to be able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Quentin it doesnt matter how Im posting from ajax, the data is being sent. This is a problem with php

Comment: @panthro — `[Object object]` is how JavaScript (by default) stringifies an object. Since JavaScript is generating that string, the problem must be on the JavaScript side.

Comment: @panthro it is set to `utf8_encode `?

Comment: also check `get_magic_quotes_gpc ` is not creating any error

Answer (score 2):

You probably try to push an object with javascript which is being cast to string. In PHP we get the result `string(15) "[object Object]"` because the string is actually `[object Object]` and you cannot get any information from it within PHP. You are making some mistake while passing the variable with javascript and you have to show us some more code to help you handle it.

Answer (score 1):

```
ctx.imageData.push({name : file.name, value : JSON.stringify(this.result)});
```

And use `json_decode` in php.

---

jQuery does not have functionality of its own for that, you have to use the browser built-in version or `json2.js` from http://www.json.org

`JSON.stringify()` is available in all major browsers, but to be compatible with older browsers you still need that fallback.

Comment: json_decode just comes back with NULL, even with adding json_decode($myVar, true)

Comment: Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.result));` and see what you get??

Comment: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4QAYRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP/sABFEdWNreQAB…1qMXeO+34oaxuI22+Ki/o8P/6Ht/SP/wCp9v4/P/b9nX/4vN/4dV6/Hf4ft/gs3p8N/j+zr//Z"

Comment: string(15) "[object Object]"

Answer (score 0):

try `json_decode()` on the variable that you are getting in the php, and after that use `var_dump` to check its value

Comment: Try to elaborate better this answer ;)